# Проблема с SDL2 image

Tags: mingw, sdl2

Добрый день уважаемые программисты. После компиляции проекта он не запускается. Выдает ошибку, представленную на скриншоте. Пользовался компилятором MInGW. SDL настроил по гайдам Lazyfoo(http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php). На другой машине под линукс данный проект нормально компилируется и запускается. SDL2 версии 2.0.8, а SDL2_image версии 2.0.3[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Какой именно у вас MinGW (покажите вывод `g++ --version`)? Откуда вы взяли SDL2_image? (Компилировали сами или взяли готовый? Если готовый, то откуда скачивали?) С какими флагами компилируете программу?

Comment: MinGW версии GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
SDL2_image взят отсюда(https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)
Компилировал сам
Флаги:
CPPFLAGS= -c -W -Wall -std=c++11 -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -IE:\MINGW\SDL2\include\SDL2 -LE:\MINGW\SDL2\lib 
SDLFLAGS=   -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -IE:\MINGW\SDL2\include\SDL2 -LE:\MINGW\SDL2\lib

Comment: А не пробовали заранее скомпилированную версию, которая по ссылке есть?

Comment: Побывал. С начало использовал библиотеки для разработчиков. Потом просто исполняемые файлы. Результата никого. Весь интернет испенал ничего. Посмотрел кучу гайдов по настройки все так же. Осталось только виндовс переустановить

Comment: Ладно, а как вы определили, что проблема в SDL2_image? В ошибке про нее ни слова.

Comment: Потому что проблема с проектом, в котором используется SDL2_image. В проекта без SDL2_image работает все нормально

Comment: А если создать новый проект из одного .cpp файла, в котором кроме инклуда и вызова `IMG_Init` ничего нет, то ошибка та же самая?

Comment: Хммм...Работает